# How to get data from input box from unity ? when clicked on submit button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get the text from from a Unity `InputField` box when I click on a button?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class input : MonoBehaviour
{
    public  InputField name;

    void Start()
    {
        var input = ToString(name);
        Debug.Log(name.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: [`InputField.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html)?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void click() {
    Debug.log(name.text);
}
```

Make the button perform the click function.

[How to add a function to a button](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1357450/how-can-i-add-a-event-onclick-for-a-ui-button-that.html)